# Nest tables in powerpoint

Tags: vba, nested, powerpoint, shapes

Is it possible to nest tables in Powerpoint using VBA?

Like:

```
 Set table = presentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Table

 Set shapeContainingTable = presentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Duplicate(1)
 
'not supported operation
 table.Rows(1).Cells(1).Shape = shapeContainingTable
```

The issue is that I have some template rows which I need to "duplicate"
in the table and then fill with data.

Now copy and paste the predefined rows is not working well with merged cells
and I wondered If there isn't a simple way to insert any kind of shape into a table cell.

Any experience with nested tables in powerpoint ?

### Container for shapes

Alternatively I could use some sort of list container for shapes
if it exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A table cell by definition contains a shape already; it's not a container for multiple shapes, so it's not possible to insert a table into a cell in a table.